# How do I call a function before every email send?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakeemail

I have about 50 different email templates whose text changes dynamically based on who the recipient is. Rather than make a different template for every possible case and include similar logic across dozens of different controller files, I want to include some case switching within each template and apply a case determining variable to every email.

For example a typical template might look like this:

```
<? if ($case) { ?>
    <p> text variation 1 </p>
<? } else { ?>
    <p> text variation 2 </p>
<? } ?>
```

`$case` would be set by a function `beforeEmail($to_address)` that does all the calculations for the cases based on the recipients email. These calculations are the same for every single email. How can I get `beforeEmail()` to get called every time an email sends? Or more accurately, *where* do I put a `beforeEmail()` function?

Normally I would stick this kind of code in the view files controller, but email view-files don't have a controller. I've played around with making `beforeEmail()` a static function somewhere and call it in each view file, but that just seems messy and wrong (It leaves me with function calls inside view files, and duplicate code accross 50+ files).

Edit: I also tried setting the `$case` variable in a layout file, but it turns out layouts are loaded AFTER the email view file is, so variables set inside a layout can't be used in a view file.

Comment: Read about Cake Events http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar problem, I ended up modifying the core CakeEmail libraries send() method. While it's not ideal, it was the only way I could find to get the behavior I wanted (Without creating duplicate code everywhere).

Things that don't work:

-Callbacks/events - The CakeEmail class doesn't offer callbacks.

-Creating a custom transport - Transports are called *after* the email is rendered.

-Putting code in a common layout file - Layouts are rendered *after* the email's view file is rendered.